# How to get daily data from Fingerprint attendance machine?

Tags: python, fingerprint, time-and-attendance

How to get daily data from Fingerprint attendance machine?I planning to use zk device and use with zklib with python.

After I learned zklib , I get all attendances datas.But i want to get specific date range or daily.

How can i get data.
And recommend require attendace machine used with python.

Comment: Does your device have an IP address? Where does it save its data in an XML or sqlite file? Once you know these, you could easily write code that connects to that host (device) and fetch clock in and click out data captured by your biometric attendance device. The good thing is that you have the API for the ZK fingerprint reader device which will hasten your development time.

Comment: Thanks cricket,I have already get data with pyzk lib.You can see on python.org.This lib gave all attendance stored in their db like 50000 transactions.Actually this all transaction is we don't need.We need daily .So i want to use which attendance machine can give daily attendnace and must also have python lib.

Comment: got any answers? I am facing the same issue.